# Which Strategy to use to implement Enterprise Integration Patters for a "data collecting" style application

Tags: architecture, esb

I'm investigating the usage of Enterprise Integration Patters in our application as a replacement of current architecture, but I have some unclear situation how to use it for our system. (Regardless what implementation we of EIP we use.)

What we have is a system that receives various kind of messages (lets mark them message type A,B (MT-A, MT-B)) for each case. For each message we are calling various external systems (around 15 of them), through web-services or kind of file protocols, etc. All this data is then transformed into our domain model, saved to database (lets say its a Canonical Domain Model (CDM)).

1. The first problem is when I receive a message (MT-A) what I want to do is to call a Web-Service using data from the message. Process the response, in next few steps (lets say do some transformation, save it do DB, etc). But then I want to continue processing with my original message and thus call other systems using data from it. But now as the message payload in the process flow have the response from web-service. What it the best way, to get back the original message I was using at the beginning before I called my external system ? (Should I use message store for this, also I saw somewhere as a quite ugly workaround to put the original message in the header.)
2. Lets say I received a few messages for a case, where some data from them, also from external systems are now in our database / CDM. Then I receive a message MT-B where I'm calling other kind of systems, but for the call I need my data from the received message, also data from  database / CDM from the previous processes. So how should I get that data. So I was thinking of 2 solutions:

   2.1. As I fist step I integrate the received message to my CDM then my payload for message in the process will be my whole CDM, thus I have everything I need in my hand. (This would solve also point 1.)

   2.2. Put the case ID in the header to which this message is related, so in case I need some data from my CDM I will just query it inside the service or endpoint where I'm calling the external system.

So which one of these solutions are preferred for such situations, probably some other ones. Or maybe I just don't see or understand the ESB-s clearly, I'm quite new to the topic. 
Note: Here I understand the Canonical Domain Model as a general domain model for application stored in database, where I have all the data from I need. (From messages also external systems)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are asking is appropriate to the Messaging Architecture. And, eh, which tool is better for you is a question, which may produce holy war. Of course me, as a developer of Spring Itegration, will protect my 'child'. From other side Apache Camel does almost the same, but a bit differently...
It's up to you which tool to choose. I suggest from a start read the [EIP Book](http://www.eaipatterns.com). 
And pay attention to patterns: **Aggrgator, Claim-Ckeck, Content Enricher, Message Store**

From case of Spring Integration: it written on Spring, it uses Spring, it is used by Spring.
So, everything what you need in this case - just Spring! ;-)
Here is our new architecture: [The Spring IO Platform](https://spring.io/platform)

And I'll be glad to see other opinions!

Comment: Hi, I don't meant this to be about implementations of EIP, n fact I will erase these 2 product from the introduction. I'm currently reading that book. And this should be about some general architectural solution...

Comment: Could you also explain, in more depth how do you picture the usage of these solution for case 1 and 2 ? thx

Comment: Case #1: Content Enricher.

Comment: Case #1: **Content Enricher**. You the original message to some subflow and wait response. Than you 'enrich' you original message with something from that response, if needed and send it furher. Case #2: Claim Check. You store your message to the DB and send the result to Aggregator. You receive the second message (keep in mind: with the same correlation key) and send it to aggregator. The last one release the group of messages and sends it to some re-claim handler. Samples are here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples